# html — positioning boxes

Tags: html, position

I want to place three boxes on a page — one on the left, taking about the same vertical space as two on the right — with multi-line content in each box, and the three boxes not touching one another.

I've done this by placing one table cell on the left and on the right a two-row table, one single-cell row above the other. Each cell has borders, to make it look as though there is a box around the contents.

My question is: is this the most standard way I can achieve the effect I want in HTML? It seems like an awful lot of code for the effect.

**HTML**

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="boxed">Multi-line content<br />
         left side</td>
      <td>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="boxed">Multi-line content<br />
                 top right side</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="boxed">Multi-line content<br />
                 bottom right side</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
.boxed {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
}

table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 10px;
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common way to do this is using "css float"..

```
float: right;
float: left;
```

There is your code: http://jsfiddle.net/HgjKc/1/

If you want them to take same vertical space define a "height" value in css..

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using tables, they are very outdated and require a lot more code than `<div>` or `<span>`. Using `<div>` or `<span>` you will be able to control your website much better with lesser html.

Comment: "Why are you using tables?" — that's the question I hope you'll help me answer. I am returning to HTML after about 15 years away from it. How are these things done now?

Comment: Tables are now only used for displaying data in like real tables....but for containing and positioning purposes `<div>` or `<span>` with CSS is used. For a better reference of HTML5 see: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_intro.asp